# Subroutine argument apparently lost in loop

Tags: perl, foreach, arguments

I have a `CGI` script pulling bibliography data from a `BibTeX` file, building `HTML` from it. It uses `CGI::Ajax` to call the subroutine below with one or two arguments. Most of the time, it will be a search term that is passed as `$s`, but if I pass a string through my `HTML` form, the subroutine will not be entirely happy with it. There is a `foreach` loop checking the entries and jumping over the entries that do not match. Now I can print the argument outside this loop alright, but the loop itself won’t print anything for `$s`, nor will it find any entries matching it. If within the loop `$s` were simply empty, the subroutine would print the entire bibliography, but this is not the case.

Basically it is as if `$s` passed as an argument breaks the loop, whereas an explicit definition in the subroutine works fine.

Here is a simplified version of my code. Please excuse sloppy or ignorant coding, I’m just dabbling in Perl.

```
sub outputBib {
    my ( $self,$s,$kw ) = @_;
    my @k;
    @k = ('foo','bar'); # this is fine
    @k = keys (%{$self->{_bib}}); # this causes problems
    foreach my $k (@k) {
        $output .= "Key = $k<br/>";
        $output .= "Search Term = $s<br/>";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

The problem seems to be the array built from the keys of the `$self->{_bib}` hash. It is odd that

1. the loop is fine when `$s` is not passed through `CGI::Ajax`. All elements are processed.
2. as soon as the subroutine is called with `$s`, the loop does not return anything.
3. if `@k` is defined as a straightforward array, the loop works and `$s` can be printed within the loop;

I build `$self->{_bib}` like so:

```
sub parseBib {
    my ( $self ) = @_;
    while (my $e = new Text::BibTeX::Entry $self->{_bibFileObject}) {
        next unless $e->parse_ok;
        my %entry_hash;
        $entry_hash{'title'} = $e->get('title');
        $entry_hash{'keywords'} = $e->get('keywords');
        $self->{_bib}{$e->key} = \%entry_hash;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please supply a minimal example of your problem. In the process of removing clutter, it is also likely that you find the solution by yourself.

Comment: I agree, I (can't|don't want to) figure out all that is going on here. As you remove non-essential code, you will help yourself and us locate the offending code.

Comment: If you can print the value of $s outside of the loop but not inside, the loop must not be executing. Have you tried printing $k to confirm that you are entering the loop? Note that when running as a CGI, you can use `warn` to send debug statements to the Apache error log. Then tail the error_log to see what is actually going on. Some indenting inside loops would help with readability too.

Comment: I hope everything under `$self->{_bib}` is already escaped for HTML output!  (If anything is there -- Jim Brandt's comment is right on.)  Separately, your loop, if it executes, replaces `$s` with `normunacString($s)` on every iteration, which seems wasteful at best.

Comment: Can you please include the lines where you are calling outputBib

Comment: @Dre I hooked outputBib to a `CGI::Ajax` function which is called like this: `"output$pid\_Search( ['search_input'$params_kw], ['text'] );`. `$pid` will be `Bib` on the corresponding page, `params_kw` puts in the second argument if it’s there and makes sense (to call `outputBib()` it does), or else nothing. Output is then sent to the the `text` `div`. I assume this part of the code is ok, it works for other search functions.

Comment: @pilcow Although `$self->{_bib}` seems to cause the problem, its contents print fine if I just loop through all of the entries. Trouble starts when `$s` comes into play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to use `warn`/`print STDERR` to verify on the live running copy that, when called via `CGI::Ajax`, all of your variables (`$self`, `$s`, `$kw`, `$self->{_bib}`) have the values that you're expecting.  Although I'm a big fan of `CGI::Ajax`, it does a fair bit of magic behind your back and it may not be calling `outputBib` in quite the way you think it is.

Also keep in mind that CGI operates on a per-*request* model, not per-*page*.  Are you perhaps populating `$self->{_bib}` when you send the initial page (and also doing all of your successful tests in that environment), then expecting it to still be there when the AJAX requests come in?  If so, you're out of luck - you'll need to rebuild it in the AJAX handler, either within `outputBib` or earlier in your code, before you call `->build_html` and hand it off to `CGI::Ajax`.

Comment: Thank you! Silly me. I had placed `$self->parseBib()` in a conditional environment, so if a `CGI` parameter said that the page was going to be a bibliography it would then parse the `BibTeX` file upon building the `HTML`. Which was fair enough as such, because only this page needed `$self->{_bib}`. `CGI::Ajax`, however, did not again check `CGI` parameters and go through all conditions with them, so a request was never fed with a populated `$self->{_bib}`. So basically I was trying to be too economic, but I assume one could do some trickery to make it work. Thanks for all the help!